# Apply the same random color to several list elements?

Tags: list-manipulation, color

I would like to apply a random color to several list elements. For example:

```
Style[{x, y}, RandomColor[]]
```

> [image]

makes the list itself colored. But I want the elements to be colored separately, not the list itself. If I do

```
(Style[#, RandomColor[]] &) /@ {x, y}
```

> [image]

only the elements get colored, but they get a different color each. Of course I can fix this by writing

```
rColor[x_]:=Block[{rd},
  rd=RandomColor[];
  (Style[#, rd] &) /@ x
]
```

So that

```
rColor[{x, y}]
```

> [image]

which is the desired output.
But it just does not feel right to write a whole block for such a simple function. Is there a one-line solution that produces the desired output?

Comment: `randomStyle[] :=
 With[{c = RandomColor[]}, Style[#, c] &];

randomStyle[] /@ Range[10]` You can leave off the `[]` from `randomStyle`, but I prefer it this way because it makes it clear that `randmoStyle` evaluates *once* and returns something (another function).

Comment: @Szabolcs just tried `With[{c = RandomColor[]}, Style[#, c] &] /@ {x, y, z}` and it works like a charm. Thank you! You should post this as an answer, and I will upvote and accept.

Comment: Why is `With` preferable to `Block` in this case?

Comment: I didn't post it because I thought it wasn't different enough from Bill's.  It just encapsulates the colour into the generated function. @bills `With` replaces `c` by an actual colour within the `Function`. `Block` would just give a temporary value to `c`, but `c` still exist as a variable that needs to be evaluated to get the colour.

Comment: @bills I might be wrong, but I believe `Block` transports the entire input to a local scope, applies the operations within the `Block` and returns the entire list as an output. The `With` modifies the function itself before it is applied.

Comment: `BlockRandom[Style[#, RandomColor[]] ]& /@ {x, y, z, w}`?

Comment: @kglr This would have been the best solution yet, if only it generated different colors on different evaluations (but the same color within one evaluation).

Comment: @Kagaratsch, you can get different colors in every invocation using  `RandomColor[];
BlockRandom[Style[#, RandomColor[]] ]& /@ {x, y,z,w}`, but your `rColor` is much cleaner than this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not so fancy:

```
Thread[Style[{x, y}, RandomColor[]]]
```

Comment: Using this as `rColor[x_] := Thread[Style[x, RandomColor[]]]` is perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I love Stitch's work-around, but following the logic that sometimes `Thread` cannot replace `Map` another method is to simply pre-evaluate the body of the `Function` wish you map.  This is essentially what Szabolcs's proposal does but a bit more direct.

```
Evaluate @ Style[#, RandomColor[]] & /@ {1, 2, 3}
```

[image]

An example usage contrasting with `Thread` is when you want a different *levelspec*:

```
Map[
  Evaluate @ Style[#, RandomColor[]] &,
  {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}},
  {2}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
rc = RandomColor[]; Style[#, rc] & /@ {x, y}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I plan to use the function in a larger expression, so that saving the random color to a separate variable before applying the Style is exactly what I would like to avoid. (In this sense, your code is equivalent to my hacky solution using `Block`.)